# Different predict result by random forest

Tags: r, random-forest

When fitting random forest, I get different predict result. Here is my code:

```
library(randomForest)
rf = randomForest(Species~., data = iris)
p1 = predict(rf, iris)
p2 = predict(rf)
mean(p1==p2) 
# result: [1] 0.9466667
```

I expect `mean(p1==p2) == 1`,but I think `p2 = predict(rf)` should also give prediction on same data `iris` i.e train set data if not given `newdata`
Why this result arises?

Comment: If you check `?predict.randomForest`, `newdata -a data frame or matrix containing new data. (Note: If not given, the out-of-bag prediction in object is returned.`  In other words, both predictions should never be the same

Comment: I can't quite get it, why do you expect the result to be the same?

Comment: @NelsonGon Because `predict.lm` will give fitted value just like give prediction on train data set if `newdata` is not given

Comment: @akrun Thanks. The reason why I expect so is that `predict.lm` will give fitted value just like give prediction on train data set if `newdata` is not given

Comment: @Spaceship222  It is easier to get distracted because of the method dispatch and we may not know if it is the same `predict` or not unless we check explicitly